# Writing to a file in ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, system-calls

I am fairly new to ARM Assembly (using the raspberry pi) and I am unable to write to a file.

The code I've written below calls an array's address into R3 (called from a C++ driver), then is supposed to output the array's contents to a file.

Unfortunately, I'm finding that my array is storing fine (as I can see the registers the next number), but the integer I am attempting to save on a file is lost. In the debugger, I can see the value being placed into R1, but then it's not being written to a file (these are integers from the range 1-100).

I've found various x86 solutions, as well as solutions regarding strings, but I am unable to find help with regard to integers.

I am utilizing the text from the book i've been provided, but it doesn't seem to help me understand.

```
output:
    mov r5, #0
externalSave:
    LDR     R0, =fileOutput             @name of file required
    MOV     R1, #0101                   @write ONLY + create file if it does not exist/overwrite
    LDR     R2, =0666                   @accessability to users assigned
    MOV     R7, #5                      @R7 = SYSCALL = 'open'
    SVC     0
    MOV     R9, R0                      @backup to R9 the file descriptor value
write:
    cmp     r6, r5                      @Comparison between Array size and count
    ble     writeEnd
    add     r3, r4, r5, LSL #2          @4 Byte shift to grab next value in array
    add     r5, r5, #1                  @Increase counter
    LDR     R1, [R3]                    @R1 = value in array R3 = Address of Array
    MOV     R11, R1                     @backup of integer to write to file
    MOV     R2, #4                      @R2 = number of bytes to write out
    MOV     R0, R9                      @R0 = requires file descriptor value
    MOV     R7, #4                      @R7 = SYSCALL = 'write'
    SVC     0


skipCENDL:
    CMP     R6, R5
    BEQ     writeEnd
    B       write

writeEnd:
    MOV     R0, R9
    MOV     R7, #6
    SVC     0

exit:
    mov r0, r6
    ldr r1, =return
    ldr lr, [r1]
    bx lr
```

Comment: Isn't `R1` supposed to contain _the address of_ the data to write?